# Replacing a word with another word without replacing another word which contains a similar substring in the same sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, substring, replaceall

I'm trying to replace a word with another word, specifically "has" with "had". But the string contains the word "hash" which has the substring "has" so it also gets replaced. What can I do to fix this?

```
function replace() {
    sentence = sentence.replaceAll("has", "had");
}
```

Comment: One simple way of solving it is to replace ' has ' (with space before and after) with ' had '. A maybe better way would be using `replace()` with a RegExp like `/\bhas\b/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place word boundaries around the word to be replaced:

```js
var input = "A man who has an appetite ate hashed browns";
var output = input.replace(/\bhas\b/g, "had");
console.log(output);
```

Note that I used regular `replace` along with the `/g` global flag.  This should have the same behavior as using `replaceAll`.